# What exactly does a git pull --rebase does

Tags: git

What exactly happens when I run the command

`git pull --rebase` on master branch

Does this rewrite my master branch history

Is it a good way to pull changes or should we

```
 1. Git fetch 
 2. Git merge
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [git rebase vs git merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge)

Comment: `rebase` ensures a linear history contrary to `merge`. It's a good idea to `rebase` when you want to have a cleaner history for one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `git pull --rebase`, a few things happen:

1. `git fetch origin master`

   -just using origin/master as an example
2. `git rebase origin/master`

   - moves all of your commits after the commits on origin/master

At this point, you can now push to origin and your commits will be applied on top of all other commits cleanly.

Without the `--rebase` flag, you'd end up with a merge commit; one that has two parents: your master branch and the work on origin/master

Here are a few helpful resources:

1. http://viget.com/extend/only-you-can-prevent-git-merge-commits
2. http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html